# Change Password in hashed function in laravel 5.6

Tags: authentication, passwords, laravel-5.6

I want to change my password which is been hashed while saving.

How can i change the password?

```
'password' => Hash::make($data->password).
```

My Controller

```
$request->validate([
    'oldpass' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:newpass',
]);

$id = $request->id;
$users = Auth::user()->whereId($id)->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($oldpass == $user->password) {
        $user->update([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newpass)
        ]);
        return view('\balance');
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Hash::check($old_password, $hashed_password)`, something like this:

```
public function passwordChange(Request $request, User $user_name) {

    // find the loggedin user
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

    // validate rules
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        'old_password' => 'required|min:6',

        'password' => 'required_with:password_confirmation|required|min:6',

        'password_confirmation' => 'confirmed|required|min:6',

    ]);

    // what to do if validator fails
    if ($validator->fails()) {

      return redirect($user->user_name . '/settings')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    } else {

        $old_password = $request->input('old_password');

        $new_password = $request->input('password');

        $hashed_password = Auth::user()->password;

        // checking the old pass with new one
        if (Hash::check($old_password, $hashed_password)) {

            $user->update([

                'password'=> Hash::make($new_password)

            ]);

            return redirect($user->user_name . '/settings')->with('success', 'Your Password updated.');

        } else {

            return redirect($user->user_name . '/settings')->with('success', 'Your Old password is wrong!');

        }

    }

}
```

Please also notice `'password' => 'required_with:password_confirmation` and `'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:newpass'` on validator. Hope it helps.

Comment: This function first checks the validation rules and if they were ok, then checks the password matching. I've tested the function above and it works and you don't need any loop. Do you have any issue with the sample?

Comment: No error in validation part.  Only on `if (Hash::check($old_password, $hashed_password))`   this Hash::check() condition fails