# Laravel Password reset not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, hash

I have a situation where the lavavel password authentication doesnt seem to pick up a  password reset. New passwords for new users work Im stuck on creating a reset.

```
 $email = $request['email'];
  //$pwmail = (string)str_random(10);
  $pwmail = (random_str(4));
  //$pwmail = '1234';
  $password = \Hash::make($pwmail);

  $userscon2 = \DB::table('users')->where('email',$email )->update(['password' => $password]);
```

I have printed the hashes out and compared them with whats in the database and they match. Part of my login  Controller below

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
    return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I have also happened to give bcrypt a try as well.

Comment: What's not working? Is users can not log in?

Comment: Is it throwing any errors ? try checking laravel logs.

Comment: No errors no logs which is much more strange.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Its a Laravel Framework version 5.1.46 (LTS) version

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a `Hash::check($new_password, $db_password)` to check the new password with the current one, before an attempt to login. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866758/4428809) might gives you an idea. Also, please see the version 5.1 [Hashing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/hashing#basic-usage).